# TypeError: Init Only takes 1 positional Argument

Tags: python, django

I am using `Class Based Views` to render my templates. Here is my code so far:

Views.py:

```
class CashFlowView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "visualization/cash_flow.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CashFlowView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response_kwargs.setdefault('content_type', self.content_type)
        return self.response_class(
            request=self.request,
            template=self.get_template_names(),
            context=context,
            using=self.template_engine,
            **response_kwargs
        )
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import CashFlowView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'cash-flow', CashFlowView, name='cashflowView')
]
```

As you can see I am using the `templateView` but I get this a weird init error. Any ideas?:

```
Internal Server Error: /visualization/cash-flow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andy/Documents/venv_analytics/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/andy/Documents/venv_analytics/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/andy/Documents/venv_analytics/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your *TemplateView* using its `as_view` method:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'cash-flow', CashFlowView.as_view(), name='cashflowView')
]
```

Comment: OMG how did i miss that? :(